# CS50 Refueling DID NOT RAISE <class 'ZeroDivisionError'>

Tags: python, unit-testing, cs50

I am really struggling on this question. I don't understand why am i failing this the test for expecting a ZeroDivisionError and keep on getting  DID NOT RAISE <class 'ZeroDivisionError'>. In my fuel.py I had already tested that ZeroDivisionError is raised when denomnator is zero yet is still doesn't works.

Code for fuel.py:

```
def main():
    percentage = -1
    while percentage == -1:
        fraction = input('Fraction: ')
        percentage = convert(fraction)
    return_val = gauge(percentage)
    print(return_val)


def convert(fraction):
    try:
        #if / not in fraction, not enough values to unpack so ValueError
        numerator, denominator = fraction.split('/')
        numerator = int(numerator)
        denominator = int(denominator)
        percentage = round((numerator/denominator)*100)
        if percentage > 100:
            raise ValueError
        else:
            return percentage
    except ValueError:
        return -1
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return -1



def gauge(percentage):
    if percentage <= 1:
        return 'E'
    elif percentage >= 99:
        return 'F'
    else:
        return f'{percentage}%'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Code for test_fuel.py:

```
from fuel import convert, gauge

import pytest

def test_gauge():
    assert gauge(1) == 'E'
    assert gauge(50) == '50%'
    assert gauge(99) == 'F'

def test_convert():
    assert convert('5/3') == -1
    assert convert('1/2') == 50
    with pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError):
        convert('5/0')
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        convert('cat/dog')
```

Comment: Apparently the function `convert` is *expected* to raise ZeroDivisionError. Instead, it catches it and returns -1.

Comment: But I had tried to raise ZeroDivisionError when denominator is 0 however it still doesn’t works

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I had figured it out already, basically pytest.raises() expects the convert() function to manually RAISE a ZeroDivisionError instead of the ZeroDivisionError be caught in the  function

Comment: I don't think you need to manually raise `ZeroDivisionError`. Just let it be raised by the division operator and then *don't try to catch it*. The exception will then be propagated to the caller.

Comment: So the main point here is to not catch the error right? Or else it fails. What we want is the convert function to raise it but not catch it right

Comment: I believe so. The exception (better to call it that than "error") is raised by the `/` operator; you don't need a `raise` statement.